# Element with auto height overflowing with `overflow-y: scroll`

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

So this problem has haunted me for a while, and despite the many other potential threads and answers to similar issues I still can't figure it out.

I have a layout mixed with CSS Grid and Flexbox, and the left sidebar contains a number of buttons that should be scrollable. So far this works fine, but I can't figure out why the sidebar makes the entire layout stick out of its parent once I set `overflow-y: scroll` to it.

[image: example demo of problem]

Looking at it, the layout always sticks out as much as the "Outer Title"'s height. Other than that, it's already flexible and adapts well to different screen heights and widths.

Can somebody explain to me this behavior and what fixes it?

**Demo:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: unset;
}

article {
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  padding: 24px;
  gap: 24px;
}

h1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  margin: unset;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#categories > button {
  width: 100%;
}

#categories .img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#icons {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#pad {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

#pad canvas {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

#pad button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar p {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Outer Title</p>

  <main>
    <h1>Inner Title</h1>

    <section id="categories">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>

      <button type="button">Up</button>

      <div id="icons">
        <button type="button" class="img">#1</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#2</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#3</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#4</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#5</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#6</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#7</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#8</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#9</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#10</button>

      </div>

      <button type="button">Down</button>
    </section>

    <section id="pad">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

      <canvas></canvas>

      <button type="button">Weiter</button>
    </section>

    <aside id="sidebar">
      <p>0:00</p>
      <button type="button">Help</button>
      <button type="button">Finish</button>
    </aside>
  </main>
</article>
```

Comment: I added a snippet with your code. In the future, don't add links to 3rd party code playgrounds when there is a code snippet functionality built in. If you do, your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the default margin from `p` is collapsing the `main` element outside of its parent. You'll notice if you set `p` to `margin: 0;` it fixes the problem.

However, the correct fix would be to put the `max-height` on `.main` as well as `.categories` since that is what is scrollable. Then set `article` to `height: max-content;`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: unset;
}

article {
  height: max-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  padding: 24px;
  gap: 24px;
}

h1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  margin: unset;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 400px;
}

#categories>button {
  width: 100%;
}

#categories .img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#icons {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#pad {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

#pad canvas {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

#pad button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar p {
  margin: auto;
}

article > p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Outer Title</p>

  <main>
    <h1>Inner Title</h1>

    <section id="categories">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>

      <button type="button">Up</button>

      <div id="icons">
        <button type="button" class="img">#1</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#2</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#3</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#4</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#5</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#6</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#7</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#8</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#9</button>
        <button type="button" class="img">#10</button>

      </div>

      <button type="button">Down</button>
    </section>

    <section id="pad">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

      <canvas></canvas>

      <button type="button">Weiter</button>
    </section>

    <aside id="sidebar">
      <p>0:00</p>
      <button type="button">Help</button>
      <button type="button">Finish</button>
    </aside>
  </main>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing `margin` from the paragraph doesn't fix the problem entirely, as the `main` still grows too much. `article` has a padding of `24px`, but the inner `main` element overflows that padding. Your suggested changes work a bit better, but I still need to set `width: 50vh` and `max-width: 700px` to #categories, which ideally should be totally dynamic depending on the parent's height.

Comment: @AndreasRemdt Remove the `margin` from `article > p`. `.main` does not grow out of `article` at all when that happens. No overflow going on in the snippet I provided if you even looked at it. "Your suggested changes work a bit better, but I still need to set `width: 50vh` and `max-width: 700px` to #categories" - you don't have this in your original code nor mentioned anything about it. What isn't known to me I simply cannot help you with. Also, I did nothing with the `width`'s on `#categories` so do as you please. My solution covers exactly what you asked for in the question.